# Using rodbc package to query sql server from R. Need to pass in date/time value into sqlQuery as part of where statement

Tags: sql-server, r

Using rodbc package to query sql server from R. Need to pass in date/time value into sqlQuery as part of where statement

```
btime <- "2016-10-17 18:00:00"
etime <- "2016-10-17 19:00:00"

sqlQuery(cn, "select * from [blah].[blah] where metric = 'name' and date_time >= Convert(datetime, **btime**) and date_time <= Convert(datetime, **etime**)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the `RODBCext` package for this:

```
library(RODBCext)
sqlQuery(cn,
    "select * from [blah].[blah] where metric = ? and date_time >= ? and date_time <= ?",
    data = list("name",
                btime, 
                etime),
    fetch = TRUE,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`RODBCext` makes it really easy to use a parameterized query where you can place a `?` in the query code where you want to put a parameter.  Since your `btime` and `etime` are already in the appropriate format for SQL, you can pass them as strings.  I also made `'name'` a parameter in the query to avoid using quotes in the query (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html for details).

`sqlExecute` is a really convenient way to get away from working strings into your queries.

Comment: So is this sort of like `sprintf.SQL`, not that such a function exists? And I see you reference the Little Bobby Tables meme indirectly. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: library(RODBC)
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=***;database=***;UID=***;PWD=***;")
dataFetch <- sqlQuery(cn, "select top 1000 * from [dbo].[vwPerfmonDataCert] where CounterName = 'Process:% Processor Time:w3wp'")

Comment: But this does not:

Comment: library(RODBCext)
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=PSPERFINTRANET;database=***;UID=***;PWD=***;")
sqlQuery(cn, "select top 10 * from [dbo].[VWPerfmonDataCert] where metric = ?",
         data = list("Process:% Processor Time:w3wp",
         fetch = TRUE,
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

Comment: Use `sqlExecute` instead of `sqlQuery`.  Also, in your working example, you have `CounterName =`, but in your failing example you have `metric =`

Comment: So apparently I am horrible at entering comments.  Will work on that...

Comment: You're fine.  I think the biggest issue was you were using `sqlQuery` instead of `sqlExecute`.  Fix that and you probably have it.

Comment: Made changes and code works.  Thx again for your help and patience.